# How do I make the querySelector look in a specific included document only?

Tags: javascript, php, html, queryselector

On my index page I have a number of includes.

```
<section><?php include('content/content1.php') ?></section>
<section><?php include('content/content2.php') ?></section>
<section><?php include('content/content3.php') ?></section>
```

In each of them I have a unique script (and some other things which is not shown here).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>          
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Content1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/sketch.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="frame">
     <canvas></canvas>
  </div>

<script src="content/content1.js"></script>
</body>
```

The `<canvas>` tag is what the querySelector in the javascript calls to.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

This works, but only for the first content file. It seems the querySelector looks at the whole loaded page, instead of just inside the body of the document where the script is placed. Google console says: "Indentifier 'canvas' has already been declared".

I have tried setting an id on the canvas-element:

```
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas1');
```

But it's not working. How do I get around this?

Comment: In what sense is the id-based selector not working? That's how you'd do it. You could also give id or class values to the `<section>` tags and use those as part of the selector.

Comment: The javascripts are animations. In the first section, the animation is showing, but in the second and third, they're not. How can putting an id on the section help?

Comment: Note you should not be including multiple `<html>` , `<head>` and `<body>` in single page

Comment: Ultimately I think you're misunderstanding the relationship between PHP and HTML/JS. It sounds like you're trying to do some sort of templated view controller. I'd really recommend looking into some sort of MVC framework long term.

However, for now. your issue is that your `include` statements are just including the documents into HTML. Your JS is not aware of that, so it looks at all of the documents. The script can never execute in just one of those.

Comment: I'm new at this. It's just a small project i'm doing so I can learn some javascript. I will look into the MVC  when I've come a bit further. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.currentScript` to get the *tag* of the currently running script tag. From there, you can navigate to its containing `section`, and from there, get to the `canvas` descendant.

You should also put everything into an IIFE to avoid global variable collisions.

```
(() => {
  const canvas = document.currentScript.closest('section').querySelector('canvas');
  // ...
})();
```

Comment: All i had to do was to use the IIFE, and it worked! I'm not sure exactly what the document.currentScript.closest is doing. Would it do, so I dont have to use the id on the canvas tag?

Comment: Yes, if you use `document.currentScript`, the associated canvas can be selected without any other identifiers - feel free to remove the ID